# is it possible to connect an app between smartphone and pc

Tags: android, ios, windows, mobile

I'm wondering if it's possble to have an application on computer (windows or mac) with some data and connect a smartphone with the same app (app for smartphones) via wifi and get data. 
How is it possible? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Web service can help you, go through the web service articles

Comment: you can use web services for that. now it's up to you which web services would help you more? SOAP or RESTful ? SOAP are comparatively easier than RESTful.

Comment: So, after i have created my app for mobile and my software for pc, i use webservives to make them interract? Can web services transfer data secure?